# Different way to see the convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the following series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{1+\cos n}{2+\cos n}\Big)^{2n-\ln n}$$ Then the series is convergent. Indeed, note that ${\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n-\ln n}{n}}=2$ and by also $$ \Big|\frac{1+\cos n}{2+\cos n}\Big|<1$$ So. by using the root test we have $L<1.$ This finishes the proof. I believe this is correct. Is there another simple way to see this?

Comment: Technically, you need  $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{1+\cos n}{2+\cos n}\right|<1$$ Luckily, you can show: $$\left|\frac{1+\cos n}{2+\cos n}\right|\leq\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Thomas Andrews, I know that but I didn't include in my answer. Thank you . Any way , $L<1$

Comment: Yeah, don’t tell us what you know in comments, tell us in the question. It takes a little time to write the comment I wrote, and the fact that it doesn’t help you reflects your choice to waste the time of other people by *not* telling us what you know. @00GB

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Thank you so much for your advice. I will try to include enough information next time. Thanks again.